# Subtracting from two columns and having the values add up if the name is present more than once

Tags: perl, awk, hash

I am trying to parse out two columns and subtract them from one another and then add them together if the name that they corresponding to occurred more than once. I was trying to use *awk* but didn't have much success, more because of my lack of experience of using awk.

Below is some sample data and desired output as well as the script I have going so far. Keep in mind this is a generic script and not my actual script. The columns I am using are columns 3 and 4 for the subtraction value so I am going to subtract 4 from 3.

#### Sample Data

#### FILE1

```
red   13
blue  7
green 5
yellow 15
red 14
```

the first file is being used to generate a hash. if the color occurs on that list then it meets the requirements of being parsed from the second file for the subtraction.

#### FILE2

```
15 1 10 15 red
10 5 71 90 blue
15 10 15 40 blue
11 10 1 92 green
15 10 7 17 blue
```

#### Expected Output

```
  $VAR1 = {
      'red' => 2,
      'blue' => 1,
      'green' => 1,
      'yellow' => 1,
    };  

10 15 red
71 90 blue
15 40 blue
1 92 green
7 17 blue


red 5
blue 54
green 91
```

I already have part of the script that calls for if the value exists because it is being drawn from a list of another file. I am using a similar sample script as a previous example I have posted here because I am manipulating that previous script into this one.

```
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

use warnings;

my %x;

open( FILE1, $ARGV[0] ) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";
while ( my $line = <FILE1> ) {
    my @array = split( " ", $line );
    $x{ $array[0] }++;
}
close FILE1;

print Dumper( \%x );
my %count;
open( FILE2, $ARGV[1] ) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";
while ( my $line = <FILE2> ) {

    my @name = split( " ", $line );
    my $y = $name[4];

    if ( $x{$y} ) {
        print join( "  ", @name[2, 3, 4] ), "\n";
    }
}
close FILE2;

exit;
```

I don't know what would be the simplest way of achieving my goal. What would be the ideal function to use in this case? I was thinking of using a hash in the `if ( $x{ $y } )` statement but didn't know if a hash would be able to accomplish the goal of subtracting the values then adding them up if they were the same color.

Comment: "Also I realize this still needs some debugging, [...] that is why I turned off the warnings." - WTF?

Comment: this script works with it off. I am currently working to fix this.

Comment: @melpomene it is fixed :)

Comment: Why is the count 54 for `blue` ? So you add the differences 19+10+25 = 54? But `blue` occurs only one time in the first file, and later you say it should occur more than once..

Comment: I don't understand *"The columns I am using are columns row 3 and 4 for the subtraction value so I am going to subtract 4 from 3"* It doesn't make sense, and I don't see 3 or 4 anywhere in your data

Comment: It is referring to column 4 being subtracted from column 3 for each row. So for green that would 92 - 1. and if green were to occur again those two numbers would be subtracted and then added to get a total number for the color green.

Comment: @HåkonHægland the first file is being used to generate a hash. if the color occurs on that list then it meets the requirements of being parsed from the second file.

Comment: in the last `if` you can subtract col 4 from col 3, and then add the difference to for example the `%count` hash (it seems it is unused) : `$count{$y}+=($name[3]-$name[2])`..

Comment: @HåkonHægland is there a specific function/definition I can look up for what you suggested? to be better informed about the basics of that syntax

Comment: See [`perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html) and [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), see also chapter two in the book [`Programming Perl`](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk to the rescue

```
awk 'FNR == NR {          # collect the keys and count from first file
   ks[$1]++
   next
}

FNR != NR && FNR==1 {     # when switched to second file, print the counts
   print "\t$VAR1={"      # in the format
   for (k in ks) {
     print "\t\t" k "=>" ks[k] ","
   }
   print "\t};\n"
}

{
   print $3,$4,$5         # print the extract from second file
   if ($5 in ks) {        # and compute the accumulated diffs
     ss[$5] += $4 - $3
   }
}

END {                     # finally, print the accumulated diffs
   print "\n"
   for (s in ss) {
     print s, ss[s]
   }
}' file1 file2
```

Comment: It is probably not very important to print the `$VAR1={}` stuff.. it is just junk from the Perl data dumper..

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how awk would work in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made very little effort to solve this yourself, and your problem description is imprecise. Please try to keep your Perl code tidy and indented properly; I shouldn't have had to edit your question so that I could read it. And use meaningful names for your identifiers; calling a hash `%x` doesn't help anyone to understand what you have written

You should also avoid using HTML in your markup. Stack Overflow uses *markdown* which gives posts a uniform and more readable style

This program solves what I understand your problem to be

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

my %wanted;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0];
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        $wanted{$1} = 1 if /(\S+)/;
    }
}

my %counts;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[1];
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        my ($n1, $n2, $colour) = (split)[2,3,4];
        $counts{$colour} += $n2 - $n1 if $wanted{$colour};
    }
}

while ( my ($k, $v) = each %counts ) {
    print "$k $v\n";
}
```

#### output

```
green 91
blue 54
red 5
```

Comment: I asked what would be the ideal function and listed what I attempted to do as well as identified where I wanted place the command. I was asking for opinions on what was the best way to do this since I had no prior experience with arithmetic in perl not a script.

Comment: @MrPeace: If that is the intention of your question then you didn't make it clear, and it would be off topic for Stack Overflow questions. I have written a Perl program that I think does what you need; is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: Take the tour [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reexamine if this "would be off topic for Stack Overflow questions." It does what it's suppose to.

Comment: @MrPeace: Have you *read* the item that you linked to? It says you should *"Ask about ... specific programming problems"*. It also says *"Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based"*, which makes *"I was asking for opinions on what was the best way to do this"* ***off topic***. If you have a problem at all it is that you don't know enough Perl (or awk), and you are now being churlish presumably because I told you off for writing a poor question (which has a downvote and a close vote that aren't mine, so someone agrees with me)